# Is it available to change NSLayoutConstraint's priority between required and nonrequired?

Tags: ios, autolayout

As mentioned in [Documents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutconstraint#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSLayoutConstraint/priority):

> Priorities may not change from nonrequired to required, or from required to nonrequired.

However, I succeed when I tried to do so. Below is my sample code:

```
var centerConstraint: UILayoutConstraint!
var topConstraint: UILayoutConstraint!

signInButton = UIButton(type: .system)
// Some setting code
...

signUpView = UIView()
// Some setting code
...

signInView.addSubview(signInButton)

centerConstraint = signInButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: signInView.centerXAnchor)
centerConstraint.isActive = true
    
topConstraint = signInButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: signInView.leadingAnchor)
topConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh
topConstraint.isActive = true
```

I create a `signInButton` and a `signInView`. The `signInButton` has two constraints. One is with priority `.required` (default), the other one is with priority `.defaultHigh`.

And then, when user click the button, I change the priority of `centerConstraint`:

```
centerConstraint.priority = .defaultLow
```

This works fine on both iOS 13 and iOS 14 simulator, not like described in the Document:

> An exception will be thrown if a priority of required in macOS or UILayoutPriorityRequired in iOS is changed to a lower priority, or if a lower priority is changed to a required priority after the constraints is added to a view.

I am wondering if the document is outdated? Is it available to change the priority of a UILayoutConstriant between required and nonrequired?

Answer (score 1):

Curiously, that ***does*** throw an exception on `iOS 12` but not on `13` or `14`.

It's *possible* that the documentation is outdated, and it is now allowed.

Or, it's possible that it's not throwing the exception with this example, but *might* do so in other cases.

Generally speaking, it's a good idea to follow the docs (absent official conflicting information).

Note that you can set the Priority to values other than `.defaultLow` / `.defaultHigh` / `.required` ... for example:

```
.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999)
```

To get a "stronger" enforcement (if needed).